# How to wait for promise to execute in for-loop using node.js?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, promise

I'm using node.js and I have a problem using for-loop and promise. How can I wait for promise.then() before the next step of for-loop?

```js
var array = ["apple", "orange"]

for (var i in array) {
            console.log(array[i])
            var promise = //any promise, doesn't matter now 
            promise.then(function(result) {
               console.log(array[i])
            }) 
            .catch(function() {
               console.log("Promise Rejected");
            });
}
```

I expect the output to be "apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", but the actual output is "apple", "orange", "orange", "orange"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for Promise before moving to next iteration in a loop in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007766/waiting-for-promise-before-moving-to-next-iteration-in-a-loop-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use async/await to give us this behaviour. The function testAwait() will return immediately, but we'll [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the output of *getResult()* on each iteration of the loop.

```js
var array = ["apple", "orange"]

// Mock function, could represent an API call etc..
function getResult(arg) { 
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, arg + "_result"));
}

async function testAwait() {
    for (var i in array) {
        console.log("Loop counter:", i)
        console.log("Input:", array[i])
        // getResult returns a Promise, we'll _await_ it here..
        let result = await getResult(array[i]);
        console.log("Result:", result); 
    }
}

testAwait();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await to wait for execution.
Some updates in your code like -

```
async function test() {
   var array = ["apple", "orange"];
   for (var i in array) {
           try{
               console.log(array[i])
               var promise = //any promise, doesn't matter now 
               await promise;
               console.log(array[i]) 
            }catch(err) {
               console.log("Promise Rejected");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise](https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098) or [async/await](https://medium.com/tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c) for complex handling we have to use both [promise with async/await](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/node-js-concurrency-with-async-await-and-promises-b4c4ae8f4510).

**By using Promise**

```
    var array = ["apple", "orange", "mango"]

    for (var i in array) {

        console.log(array[i])

        getFruit(array[i]).then(function(item) {

            console.log(item);

        }).catch(function(error) {

            console.log(error.message);
        });

    }


function getFruit(item) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if (item == undefined) reject('array is null');

            resolve(item);

    })

}
```

**By Async and Await**

```
    const forLoop = async _ => {

        var array = ["apple", "orange", "mango"]

        console.log('Start')

        for (var i in array) {

            const numFruit = await getFruit(array[i]);

            console.log(numFruit)
        }

        console.log('End')
    }

    forLoop();


const getFruit = fruit => { return fruit; }
```